# deferred ajax not working

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using deferred Ajax using jquery. On click event of button "TestAjax" i will call 2 WCF services. when they are finished loading i will perform some logic. My code is as below

```
this.TestAjax = function () {
        debugger;
        var flattened1;
        var flattened2;




        function callFirstService() {

            ViewModel.loadFirstService(1));

       }

        function callSecondService() {

            ViewModel.loadSecondService(2);
       }

        // Multiple Ajax Requests 
       $.when(callFirstService(), callSecondService()).done(function () {

           console.log("now we are will start logic);

           // logic here                



        });



};
```

The code for calling services in different view model which is as below

```
  this.loadFirstService = function (id) {



        var input =
            {
                Id: id

            };


        $.ajax({
            url: "../RestService/someService",
            type: "PUT",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            processData: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(input),
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                alert(errorThrown);
            },

            success: function(allData) {
                var test = $.map(allData, function(item) {

                    return new Data1(item);
                });

                self.List1(test);




            }
        });

 };



 this.loadSecondService = function (id) {



        var input =
            {
                Id: id

            };


        $.ajax({
            url: "../RestService/someService",
            type: "PUT",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            processData: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(input),
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                alert(errorThrown);
            },

            success: function(allData) {
                var test = $.map(allData, function(item) {

                    return new Data2(item);
                });

                self.List2(test);




            }
        });

};
```

Issue is that it goes inside  $.when and prints   console.log("now we are will start logic); and then calls the services. How can i call services first and then perform some logic when services are hit successfully?

Let me know if its not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your methods to return deferred objects.

```
this.loadSecondService = function (id) {
    var input = {
        Id: id
    };
    return $.ajax({
        ...
    });
```

next, you need to handle the logic around receiving the data within `.done()`

```
$.when(callFirstService(), callSecondService()).done(function (firstService,secondService) {
    console.log("Both services are done");
})
```

Comment: my services are already returning data. What else should i do?

Comment: They are returning data, but they are not returning a deferred object to `$.when`. My code above shows how to change that.

Comment: didnt understood what to return after done. you have written .done(function (firstService,secondService). Where you got firstService,secondService? Please bear with me as i am new to Ajax world

Comment: the `.done` doesn't have to return anything (it can't anyway), `firstService` and `secondService` contain the data that was returned from the ajax request.

Comment: in our case for ex the service "loadSecondService" returns self.List2(). So i need to return that. so will it be like 
.done(function (self.List2(),self.List1())

Comment: @AshReva You can't, `self.List2()` and `self.List1()` need to go inside the success callbacks, or inside of the `.done` callback. Whatever makes more sense in your case.

Comment: can you explain me how to exactly do this?

Comment: I don't understand enough about what you are doing or what order your code needs to run to work properly to make a suggestion on that. The fact is loadSecondService and loadFirstService need to return a promise object. if self.List2() returns a promise object, then yes you can return that, but given what you provided in your question, i'd assume it does not return a promise object.

Comment: it should call loadFirstService,loadSecondService and then when they are finished i will perform some logice

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26485/discussion-between-ashreva-and-kevin-b)